# 'Fly USA now': grammatical/idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, idioms

An airline in my country (Germany) is currently advertising their flights to the US with the slogan "Fly USA now".

I know you can "fly Emirates", ie. on an airplane run by the airline Emirates, and you can "go West", but I don't think you can "fly USA" (unless that is US Airways which it isn't in this case).

Marketers in Germany aren't generally big on English grammar, but this seems so wrong to me that I have to ask: is this a turn of phrase that I just haven't come across yet or is it really as bad as I think it is? [image: dv]

Comment: Sounds pretty dumb to me. I have to ask, though: how does "Fliegen Bundesrepublik Deutschland" sound to you?

Comment: Like a translation from Google Translate? English tends to be more flexible though.

Comment: Chalk it up to marketers being paid on the basis of impact rather than grammar. In this case, it got you to think about it as well as to circulate the advertisement.

Comment: @Lawrence: Yeah, every marketer is a Herostratus at heart.

Comment: @Lawrence: Oh, and by the way, now that we've all been made aware of the existence of this airline and the options, do you feel an overpowering desire to fly AirBerlin as we speak? On my part, I do have a couple of friends over in Germany, but I can't picture them going, "Hey, Ricky, we want to come over, what airline should we take," much less myself going, "You know what, guys, AirBerlin sounds like the best option out there!" Ergo, no matter how much we discuss it here, AirBerlin isn't going to gain any popularity on this site.

Comment: I wish I had as much faith in people's sanity as you do, @Ricky. at least some marketers believe that any attention is good attention and they seem to have their reasons for believing it. So: sorry for circulating an ad that didn't deserve it.

Comment: @JohannesBauer: No harm done, chief! It's all good fun. Thanks for posting it. I love it!

Comment: @Ricky You never know, there may be some who might check it out :) .

Comment: @JohannesBauer: I once sat down and purposely counted all the car ads on TV in prime time on one of the big-ass national channels. Then I did some calculations. Turns out, an average American sees 55,000 car ads between car purchases. That's fifty-five thousand ads to get a person to buy one car! No product in history was pushed with such vim-and-vigor. My theory is auto companies kind of _suspect_ it's just a huge waste of money, but they're afraid to take chances; so they just leave everything as it is, useless budget-wrecking ads included.

Comment: There is the phrase "sail the seven seas", which has the same structure ([travel] [noun phrase]) as "fly USA". However, even then it translates better to "fly around USA" than "fly to USA". An odd turn of phrase in any case.

Comment: @Lawrence: Oh, yeah, like who? Frau Merkel and Til Schweiger have their own jets. Everyone else flies Air Alaska.

Comment: @Ricky The thing is, TV advertisers don't pay per viewer. If you have the stats, it would be interesting to see the average cost of advertising per car sold.

Comment: @Ricky Re: your other comment - well, I don't know about Frau and Til, but what about Gerhardt? (I've got an auto-popup to move to chat, so I'll start deleting some of my side comments soon. Johannes Bauer - sorry to hijack your question. Hope you were entertained in the mean time :) .)

Comment: It is a marketing slogan. Being grammatically correct is a low priority. It is short, easy to read as you whizz past in a car, and has a call to action, all of which matter more to marketers that grammar does.

Comment: @RoaringFish it also makes me grind my teeth. Not the reaction you normally want to inspire in your target audience. @ Lawrence: yup, I'm entertained. Still, this is not the place for chat, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: It's transitive here probably because sex sells, not because they didn't know a preposition was needed.

Comment: @JohannesBauer ~ I totally understand that, but it is probably because - like everybody else in here - you are something of a language nerd. I mean this in the best possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I certainly have never heard it. In English, such expressions require a preposition.

'Fly to the USA now'.

You can, however, say 'ﬂy home', in the same vein as 'go home'. This is because 'home' is being used as an adverb, not an accusative noun. USA however, is not an adverb, or at least, not a recognised one in common use.